# como inserto registros en una tabla relacionada con una principal

Tags: vba, ms-access

(visual basic--Access) tengo dos tablas una de pacientes con campos nombre y numero de identificacion la otra tiene lo un historial de eventos que que diariamente le suceden ahora cuando llamo a esta tabla de eventos con un formulario  y agrego un registro necesito que automaticamente se llenen los campos de esta con su nombre y nro de documento de la tabla principal para no tener que repetirlos, no tengo ni idea de como puedo hacerlo intente esto en un boto pero no se como relacionarlo con el formulario de ingreso:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO p1(nro_identificacion,nombre) " & _
      "VALUES ('" & nro0101 & "','" & nom0101 & "') "

DoCmd.RunSQL sql

Me.Recordset.MoveLast

DoCmd.OpenForm "eventos_adversos", , , "nro_identificacion= '" & nro0101 & 
"'"
```

se que para nada esta es una solucion pero necesito que al menos me acerquen a la solucion , gracias..

Comment: Combina tu INSERT INTO con un `DLookUp` que te devuelva el nombre del paciente. En español en las consultas el `DLookUp` es una función de Access que se llama `DBúsq` https://support.office.com/es-es/article/db%C3%BAsq-funci%C3%B3n-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937. Si lo estás haciendo desde VBA, con un `DLookUp` podrías traerte el nombre en una variable y llevártelo luego a `VALUES` de tu SQL

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada, en la tabla hija (la de eventos) no debes incluir el nombre; sólo el número de identificación con el que se relacionan ambas tablas (supongo que esto lo tienes claro pero me han entrado dudas por el planteamiento de tu pregunta). Este valor, si diseñas correctamente el formulario que vas a utilizar, se cubre automáticamente...

Debes tener dos formularios: uno principal en el que incluirás los controles Número y nombre del médido y otro secundario (subformulario) en el que se mostrarán los eventos.

Ambos formularios los relacionas utilizando el campo "Nro. Identificación" de ambas tablas. Esta relación la haces a través de las propiedades del subformulario indicando los valores apropiados para LinkMasterFields y LinkChildFields. Esto dice Microsoft con respecto a estas propiedades:

> "Puede usar la propiedad VincularCamposSecundarios (LinkChildFields)
>   (junto con la propiedad VincularCamposPrincipales (LinkMasterFields))
>   para especificar el modo en que Microsoft Access vincula los registros
>   de un formulario o informe a los registros de un subformulario"

.